# multithreading synchronized for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to write a multithreaded program that runs two threads. The two threads execute a for loop together and print out numbers 0 to 99. The problem I am having is each thread runs the for loop 0 to 99, so I get 0 to 99 twice instead of them working together to get to 99.

My results look like this

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

I want something like this, where each thread prints a number all the way to 100.

```
1
2
3
4
all the way to 100 then stop
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
public class JavaApplication220 implements Runnable {

    public int i;

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication220.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main() class

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication220 thread1 = new JavaApplication220();
        JavaApplication220 thread2 = new JavaApplication220();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.execute(thread1);
        executor.execute(thread2);

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: The two threads as you have written tme are completely independent of each other and do not communicate. Why would you expect them to "share" the counting?  Time to review the [Java Concurrency Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: This problem looks like homework

Comment: This is not homework believe it or not. I know how to do this in unix in c with a mutex, but not in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){


        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        i.set(0);
        TestingT thread1 = new TestingT(i);
        TestingT thread2 = new TestingT(i);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.execute( thread1 );
        executor.execute( thread2 );

        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
class TestingT implements Runnable {
    AtomicInteger i;
    TestingT(AtomicInteger i ){
        this.i = i;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(this.i.get() < 100) {
            int i = this.i.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

this should works fine with your requirements

Answer (score 0):

in case the order is required like mentioned in

> I want something like this, where each thread prints a number all the way to 100. 
>   `1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   all the way to 100 then stop`

it makes sense to do e.g. this way (only JavaApplication220 changed)

```
public class JavaApplication220  implements Runnable {
    public static int i;

    public static synchronized int getNextAndPrintIfSatisfied(int upperLimit4BeingPrinted)
    {
        if(++i < upperLimit4BeingPrinted)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void run(){
        {
            while(getNextAndPrintIfSatisfied(100) < 100)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication220.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"What am I doing wrong?"
You want to make two parallel threads work sequentially. Parallel programming is about threads working in parallel, not sequentially. For sequential execution, you should use single thread.
I suppose this is a study assignment. Tell your teacher threads are for parallel programming, not sequential.